# Cannot Access new Management Server Port in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman, spring-boot-actuator

In my Spring Boot Application I changed the default management server port in order to expose it on different port through HTTP. My main app works on HTTPS with SSL key and I don't want to expose it there.

```
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:local-ssl.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-alias=local_ssl
server.port=8443
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.server.port=8081
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus
```

However when I am trying to access the http://localhost:8081/actuator/prometheus, I am receiving the following picture from Postman. How can I access my endpoints through the new port?

[image: Postman Image]

Comment: I think it should be ‘management.port=8081‘

Comment: @Mo_- autocompletion in IntelliJ provides only this option

Comment: Was the endpoint reachable before disabling ssl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When configured to use a custom port, the management server can also be configured with its own SSL using the various `management.ssl.*` properties. For example, this allows a management server to be available via HTTP while the main application uses HTTPS:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:store.jks
server.ssl.key-password=secret
management.port=8080
management.ssl.enabled=false
```

Alternatively, both the main server and the management server can use SSL but with different key stores:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:main.jks
server.ssl.key-password=secret
management.port=8080
management.ssl.enabled=true
management.ssl.key-store=classpath:management.jks
management.ssl.key-password=secret
```

for reference look here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.4.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your info. Besides this information, I had wrong Spring Security configuration which I didn't show in my initial question. I should modify my antMatchers properly.